# defining dimensional dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to define another dimension in a dict:

```
def skidoo():
    dingo ={}
    chain = iptc.Chain(iptc.Table(iptc.Table.FILTER), "FORWARD")
    for rule in chain.rules:
        ipaddr2 = rule.dst.split("/")
        dingo[ipaddr2[0]]={}
        checkdom = open('/usr/local/ipt.log')
        for row in csv.reader(checkdom):
            if row[1] == ipaddr2[0]:
                namey = row[0]
                dingo[ipaddr2[0]]= namey
                dingo[ipaddr2[0]][namey]= row[2]             

    return dingo
```

I'm getting the ips out of iptables and then searching for that ip in a csv against the name and writing that into a dict. All fine so far. However I can't seem to assign the contents to the extra "namey" dimension.

I assumed it might be because I was in square bracket hell so I tried `[ipaddr2[0]][namey]` and `[[ipaddr2[0]][namey]]`

I either get:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

or:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I've initialized it so it knows it's a dict within a dist (I think). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dingo[ipaddr2[0]]= namey
dingo[ipaddr2[0]][namey]= row[2]
```

how can this work ?
when the 2nd line is executed, `dingo[ipaddr2[0]]` equals to whatever `namey` was which is a string, so:
you're using a string (`namey`) as an index - error
to access a location inside the same string (`namey`) - error
and assign another string at that location (`row[2]`)  - error

if what you really want is a nested dictionary, you should do something like:

```
dingo[ipaddr2[0]]= dict()
```

now you can use namey as a key of this new dict:

```
dingo[ipaddr2[0]][namey] = row[2]
```

Comment: So what's the solution? should I use dingo[ipaddr2[0]][0]=namey and dingo[ipaddr2[0]][1]= row[2]?

Comment: I've just tried it and it functionally works but it isn't the dimensional structure I'd prefer. I'll see if someone has an answer to how it might work in the format I'm after.

Comment: Actually I'll take it, it took 2 seconds to alter my output parsing appropriately.

Comment: @KeefBaker i'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, i've updated the answer with an example of a nested dict

Comment: That was what I wanted to do. Thanks!